# Reflection to grab strings from an objective c file

Tags: objective-c

I have a large objective c file filled with hardcoded objects with a description String field on them. They are all constructed like so:

```
Item *43 = [[Item alloc] initWithFieldId:@"43" description:@"This is test 43 of 100"];
```

I would like to know if there is a way for me to extract all of these strings in this .m file and write them to a text file. Is there some kind of reflection library that would let me walk this file and grab all the strings starting from description:@ ending at the second quotation mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could do it from the terminal pretty easily with a find command and some regex like Bob recommends: (edited to only echo descriptions, not entire file)

```
find . -type f -name \*.m -exec sed -n 's/Item .*description:@"\(.*\)"].*/\1/p' {} \;
```

This will return

```
This is test 43 of 100
```

for all of the matches.

For the entire line that the search finds use:

```
find . -type f -name \*.m -exec grep Item\.*description:@ {} \;
```

Comment: it returns me the entire file text but with the text "This is test 43 of 100" replacing the full version of that line. Is there a way to get ONLY this text and nothing else?

Comment: So you want the entire line of text, like "Item *43 = [[Item alloc] initWithFieldId:@"43" description:@"This is test 43 of 100"];"?

Comment: The file in question has other content around the Item * 43 lines. Right now, the above regex returns the entire file (with all the other contente) + the Item * 43 line (substituted with "This is test 43 of 100" instead of the whole original line which is what i want). I am looking to only capture instances of the various "This is test 43 of 100" by themselves in the console with no other code around them. Just those pure string values echoes back

Comment: ah yes very small change, sorry:  find . -type f -name \*.m -exec sed -n 's/Item .*description:@"\(.*\)"].*/\1/p' {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a specific pattern to the file you can use [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to extract what you need.

There are various editors that internally support regex, but you can always use regex through the Unix command line tools.

Here's a [place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).